# What is this functionality called, and is it in HTML or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to find out how this is commonly implemented, mainly because I can't seem to find it in the source code - it's the "graying out" of text that happens whenever a menu-option/button is unable to be clicked. I'm trying to find it in firebug but this is what I find for the image:

```
<input
    type="submit"
    onclick="LoadingMsg();"
    class="btnclass"
    disabled="disabled"
    id="ctl00_ctl00_Content_ContentItems_btnUpdateQuotas1"
    value="Update Quotas"
    name="ctl00$ctl00$Content$ContentItems$btnUpdateQuotas1"
>
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: It's called "disabling a form element" ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's HTML but can be implemented using JavaScript to manipulate the HTML input/select element to have that property.

This is the attribute that does it: `disabled="disabled"`

A basic example of JavaScript manipulating this attribute would be:

```
document.getElementById('elementid').disabled = true;  // Disable element
document.getElementById('elementid').disabled = false; // Enableelement
```

Resources: [disabled attribute](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/input/disabled)